# Maximize form with DoCmd.maximize not working in access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have tried to maximize my access form with
DoCmd.Maximize

But when I double click, I can see the form not getting FULLY maximized for the ENTIRE screen.
The 'Tables-queries' pane on the left side is hiding the entire view.

I tried opening some of the sample access forms downloaded from web, they all opened in full screen . Some one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For Maximize to be effective you first have to change the Access option to allow `Overlapping Windows`. Then the form itself must be the active object. One way to activate the form is:

```
    DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, "frmName"
```

You can minimize the Navigation Pane (on the left) with:

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.Minimize
```

You can minimize the Ribbon with:

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
'to show it..
'DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
```

The form will occupy the remaining space - the maximimum amount available to it. it won't occupy the ENTIRE screen.

Answer (score 0):

(Below answer is not for regular behavior. When a form modal property is set to "yes" or true, you have to type one statement outside a form to solve your problem)

If you call a form using:

**Docmd.openform "yourFormName"**

Right after those statement type again:

**Docmd.maximize**

Enjoy!